# What happened to NVD3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

This page gets a 404
https://github.com/novus/nvd3

This page is blank
http://nvd3.com/

Did something happen to NVD3 or is this just a temporary problem?

Comment: If you are looking for nvd3 with rails, try https://github.com/adeven/nvd3-rails

Comment: This question is off topic, but it looks like the project owner killed it.  As I don't work for github or novus though, I have no idea for sure.

Comment: Don't know if this question is considered off topic but this page is the only place that I found with actual information about this sad event...

Comment: NVD3 is back, for good. http://nvd3.org/statement.html

Answer (score 17):

Well [@bobmonteverde](https://twitter.com/bobmonteverde) tweeted yesterday that Novus Partners, his employer took the project down and he is going to comply with their decision as heartbroken as it left him.

Today the tweets are gone, so we can assume the project's dead. If you want the latest version, the most recent fork is [here](http://nvd3.org/statement.html).

---

**UPDATE**: from the comments of this post, most active discussion on this is currently taking place at

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/lxtnWUUnIxo/Z1vt7adPOYUJ

---

**UPDATE 2:** It's back at http://nvd3.org. Novus released [a statement](http://nvd3.org/statement.html) about NVD3.

Comment: There is a bit more discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/lxtnWUUnIxo/Z1vt7adPOYUJ)

Comment: Definitely follow the discussion that Superboggly posted as the nvd3/nvd3 mirror is no longer there. Copyright issues.